# "in all material respects"?

Tags: meaning, terminology, legalese

> The Business has been carried on in the ordinary course and all
> financial statements and other information provided for to Purchaser
> are true, accurate, and correct in all material respects.

What is the meaning of "in all material respects"?

Comment: From the full OED - **matter** Definition III 6a: *Of serious or substantial import; significant, important, of consequence.* A "metaphoric" extension from ***material = matter = physical substance.*** Note also the same kind of extension to a ***verb*** usage - *This question **matters** to me* (it's *important* to me).

Answer (score 3):

In this case **material** is used as an adjective and it means

> In all aspects that are relevant and essential (in this case, related to the business).